# RSpec + database cleaner, not cleaning correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i really can't understand why DatabaseCleaner is not cleaning my test database. This is what i get prompting

```
1.9.2p290 :007 > DatabaseCleaner.clean
```

--

```
=> [#<DatabaseCleaner::Base:0x007fa7e4dd8b58 @autodetected=true, @orm=:active_record, @strategy=#<DatabaseCleaner::ActiveRecord::Transaction:0x007fa7e4dc14f8 @db=:default>>]
```

This seems not to set correctly the database (supposed to be :test), so i got a solution like

```
 DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test].clean
 # => nil
```

The gem seems to be set up correctly:

```
1.9.2p290 :007 > DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test]

#<DatabaseCleaner::Base:0x007fe8fcfd4868 @orm=:active_record, @strategy=#<DatabaseCleaner::ActiveRecord::Transaction:0x007fe8fcfd2748 @db=:test, @connection_hash={"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}>, @db=:test>
```

This seems to setup correctly the test database, however it is still not going to clean properly the database. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your console in the correct environment? (eg rails console test) I'd expect DatabaseCleaner to clean the environment it's called in.

Comment: of course it is. opened with _rails c test_.

Comment: prompting `DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test].clean`, returns nil.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me, next potentially silly question, is your strategy set? 

`DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation`

Comment: yes it is. currently situated in spork prefork block, but also tried removing all non-required gems e.g. spork, guard, ..

Comment: Do you know how `DC` works? I mean if strategy is transaction, then it simply opens transaction after starting and rolls it back on the end. So if you do not start `DC`, it has nothing to rollback. Also, it will not delete anything that already exist in DB. `:truncation` strategy will remove existing data at the other hand.

Comment: Try this `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` and then `DatabaseCleaner.clean`

Answer (score 23):

Even with database cleaner correctly configured it is easy to leave data lying around.

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation  # clean DB of any leftover data
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction # rollback transactions between each test
  Rails.application.load_seed # (optional) seed DB
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

The configuration above starts & runs the cleaner either side of **each** test.

If you then use `before :all` in your specs you can end up with data lying around:

```
describe User do
  # Before all is outside the before :each 
  before :all do
    @user = User.create(:email => 'hello@example.com')
  end

  ...tests here
end
```

Comment: According to the spec, your recommendation is the official recommendation for MiniTest, not RSpec. https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#additional-activerecord-options-for-truncation @palominoz seems to referring to RSpec.

Comment: So what would be the alternative to `before :all`? I cannot use `let` since I need some shared data for a few tests within a `context` that should not change.

Comment: @slhck - is there a reason you can't use `before :each`? "Sharing" data between tests in a context (as opposed to creating the same data each test) sounds like a bad idea & likely to introduce order dependency.

Comment: @Peter Yes, you're right. This has already bitten me when not clearing the database between tests.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my spec_helper.rb (slightly modified) - maybe that will help you?

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: The truncation strategy doesn't require DatabaseCleaner.start before each test.

Comment: Oddly, when I do this I put DatabaseCleaner.start in the .before(:each) and .after(:each)   If i just put it in the after it doesn't always run.  That may be due to errors in a spec.

Answer (score 4):

Avdi Grimm's had a nice post recently on configuring database cleaner:

http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rails c test
> require 'database_cleaner'
> DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
> DatabaseCleaner.clean
```

https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: see this answer and comment by @mark. stick this where you want to clean: `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)`